# SysML/UML Using properties from instances in decisions

Tags: properties, uml, instance, activity-diagram, sysml

I'm new to UML and SysML and I am using Cameo Systems Modeler. My problem is concerning activity diagrams.

My plan is to use the values I specified under "slots" in an instance for a following decision. I specified one property "test" as type Integer. Its value is 7.
I dragged the instance on my activity diagram in which it appeares as a value specification with one output pin. I want to use the value 7 in the following decision: e.g. two activity edges: test<4 or test>4?). I tried naming the output pin "test" and connecting it via object flow with the decision node (the value specification node is ofc also connected to that via control flow.). Unfortunately it doesnt work this way.

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `test<4 or test>4` : you probably mean `test<=4 or test>4` or `test<4 or test>=4`. In a *value specification activity node* the output pin is named *result* and the *value specification* is given through the attribute *value*. What you mean by *it doesnt work this way*, what is the behavior ? You say you dragged an instance, an instance of what ?

Comment: Are you sure you must not use a *Read Structural Feature Actions* where the instance is received through the pin *object*, *test* is specified by *structuralFeature*, and the output pin *result* gives the value

Comment: My problem is a step further from this: I created a block. for that block i created the property "test:Integer". Then i created an Instance of the block called "testinstance". In the specification of this instance i assigned the value 7 to the property test:Integer under the tab "slots". When I drag the instance from my Containment Tree onto my activity diagram it automatically becomes a valueSpecification action. In the specification of this action i see the Instance "testinstance" in the value field. now I want to use the property of that instance in a following decision. How do i do that?

Comment: @bruno THANK YOU SO MUCH!! Your second comment was the answer to my problem!

Comment: I moved it as an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me the output pin *result* of the *value specification* corresponding to your instance must be linked to the input port *object* of a *Read Structural Feature Action* whose have *test* as *structuralFeature* and its output port *result* is linked to the *decision node*.

The output port of the *value specification* values your instance, not the value of *test* for it